# Problem in Getting Data From API in Angular

Tags: angular, api

I have Created an example for getting data from API "https://reqres.in/api/users".
I have used services and Observable in my Example .
I am Getting an Error"**Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'.Only arrays and iterables are allowed**"

Here is my Code.

employee.ts

```
export interface IEmployee{
id : number,
email : string,
first_name : string
}
```

employees.service.ts

```
import { IEmployee } from './employee';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeesService {

private _url : string = "https://reqres.in/api/users";

constructor( private http : HttpClient ) { }

getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
 return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url); 
}  
}
```

employee-list.component.ts

```
import { EmployeesService } from './../employees.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'employee-list',
templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

public employees = [];

constructor(private employeesService : EmployeesService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.employeesService.getEmployees()
  .subscribe(data => this.employees = data);  
}
}
```

employee-list.component.ts

```
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<ul *ngFor = "let employee of employees">
 <li>{{employee.email}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the response of the API?

Comment: I'm using this Open Api "https://reqres.in/api/users" , which contains                                                                              {"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth"},   {"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver"}] }

Comment: The answer below is correct. I was behind a proxy and couldn't hit the API. The extraneous properties in the response are what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to cast your data with  `<IEmployee[]>` You should get the data list first :

In **employees.service.ts** change your function `getEmployees()` :

```
getEmployees(): Observable<any>{
 return this.http.get<any>(this._url); 
}
```

Then in **employee-list.component.ts** you need to get data object list from the response.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.employeesService.getEmployees()
  .subscribe(response=> this.employees = response.data);  
}
```

Because this is how it looks the response :

```js
const response = {"page":1,"per_page":6,"total":12,"total_pages":2,"data":[{"id":1,"email":"george.bluth@reqres.in","first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"},{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},{"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"},{"id":4,"email":"eve.holt@reqres.in","first_name":"Eve","last_name":"Holt","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"},{"id":5,"email":"charles.morris@reqres.in","first_name":"Charles","last_name":"Morris","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"},{"id":6,"email":"tracey.ramos@reqres.in","first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Ramos","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"}]};

console.log(response.data);
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, i have update my answer i forget to change  Observable<IEmployee[]> to Observable<any>

Comment: Nice well done,  Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this question as the correct anwser.